# Calculation method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to write a calculate method that takes three parameters: an integer, an operator string (example: "+"), and another integer. The method should execute the operation and return the result, an integer. The method should be able to handle the +, -, *, and / operations. For example, calculate(4, '+', 5) should return 9.

I think the method should be something like this:

```
def calculator(a,'b',c)
     a.to_i b.to_s c.to_i
end


p calculator(4,'+',5)
```

I keep getting error messages. Please advise on how to call a different operator to complete this.

Comment: what does this `a.to_i b.to_s c.to_i` suppose to mean?

Comment: If the arguments are `a`, `op` and `b`, all strings, you could write `eval a+b+c` (e.g., `eval "2"+"*"+"3" #=> 6`), but if you do, the `eval` police will come after you (because `eval`, if used with abandon, can be exploited by bad people).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
def calculator(a, operation, b)
  a.send(operation, b)
end

calculator(1, '+', 3)
#=> 4
calculator(3, '*', 2)
#=> 6
```

Comment: Has the added benefit of working with symbols (`:+`, `:*`) too.

Answer (score -2):

You should read about what is method signature and what is [switch](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) statement.
If you don't want to bother with understanding you can use ruby **send** method.

EDIT:
[How to define method in Ruby](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm)